# How to use TLS 1.0 with Python 3.8?

Tags: python-3.x, ssl, openssl, jira, urllib3

I have a code that connects with Jira using `jira` module.
Unfortunately Jira server only supports `SSLv3` and `TLS1`.
**I know they are old protocols**, host will accept new ones before the end of this year.
But until there I need my python code to connect on Jira using `TLS1`.

With Python 3.6 it worked fine, but with Python 3.8 it doesn't work, it shows me the error message below.

```
Python 3.8.2 (default, Apr 27 2020, 15:53:34) 
[GCC 9.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from jira import JIRA
>>> import urllib3
>>> urllib3.disable_warnings(urllib3.exceptions.InsecureRequestWarning)
>>> 
>>> options = {"server": "https://jira.mycompany.com/", "verify": False}
>>> jira = JIRA(options, auth=("user", "pass"))
WARNING:root:HTTPSConnectionPool(host='jira.mycompany.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /rest/auth/1/session (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: UNSUPPORTED_PROTOCOL] unsupported protocol (_ssl.c:1108)'))) while doing POST https://jira.mycompany.com/rest/auth/1/session [{'data': '{"username": "user", "password": "pass"}', 'headers': {'User-Agent': 'python-requests/2.23.0', 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate', 'Accept': 'application/json,*.*;q=0.9', 'Connection': 'keep-alive', 'Cache-Control': 'no-cache', 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'X-Atlassian-Token': 'no-check'}}]
WARNING:root:Got ConnectionError [HTTPSConnectionPool(host='jira.mycompany.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /rest/auth/1/session (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: UNSUPPORTED_PROTOCOL] unsupported protocol (_ssl.c:1108)')))] errno:None on POST https://jira.mycompany.com/rest/auth/1/session
{'response': None, 'request': <PreparedRequest [POST]>}\{'response': None, 'request': <PreparedRequest [POST]>}
WARNING:root:Got recoverable error from POST https://jira.mycompany.com/rest/auth/1/session, will retry [1/3] in 7.597192960254091s. Err: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='jira.mycompany.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /rest/auth/1/session (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: UNSUPPORTED_PROTOCOL] unsupported protocol (_ssl.c:1108)')))
```

I already checked and OpenSSL supports `TLS1`.

```
$ openssl s_client -help 2>&1  > /dev/null | egrep "\-(ssl|tls)[^a-z]"
 -ssl_config val            Use specified configuration file
 -tls1                      Just use TLSv1
 -tls1_1                    Just use TLSv1.1
 -tls1_2                    Just use TLSv1.2
 -tls1_3                    Just use TLSv1.3
 -ssl_client_engine val     Specify engine to be used for client certificate operations
```

Using only `requests` it gives me the same result.

```
python3 -c "import requests; requests.get('https://jira.mycompany.com/')"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/lazize/repos/myproj/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 670, in urlopen
    httplib_response = self._make_request(
  File "/home/lazize/repos/myproj/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 381, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "/home/lazize/repos/myproj/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 976, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File "/home/lazize/repos/myproj/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 361, in connect
    self.sock = ssl_wrap_socket(
  File "/home/lazize/repos/myproj/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py", line 377, in ssl_wrap_socket
    return context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=server_hostname)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/ssl.py", line 500, in wrap_socket
    return self.sslsocket_class._create(
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/ssl.py", line 1040, in _create
    self.do_handshake()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/ssl.py", line 1309, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLError: [SSL: UNSUPPORTED_PROTOCOL] unsupported protocol (_ssl.c:1108)
```

How can I use Python 3.8 with `TLS1`?

Comment: Python 3.8 usually supports TLS 1.0 so likely there is something else wrong here (but no way to reproduce it for us). Also, the command line options given by `openssl s_client` say nothing about the supported TLS protocols by your Python version.

Comment: It might be a better use of your time to try instead to upgrade your Jira instance to stop having to rely on decades old protocol that are now being phased out everywhere. Specially because any change you may need to do may become global and hence affect the whole security of your system, which is bad. I am sure this is not what you wanted to read, but it is honestly what makes more sense in the long run. The world should run on TLS 1.2 now, at least (1.3 being even better of course but at least we have the excuse it is too new; SSLv3, TLS1.0 and 1.1 are old and dangerously broken)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue installing python package below.
In this way it installed `pyOpenSSL`.

Let me quote documentation:

> If you install urllib3 with the `secure` extra, all required packages
>   for certificate verification will be installed.

```
pip install urllib3[secure]
```

If I understood correct Python comes with its own implementation of `SSL` via module `ssl`.
Installing `urllib3` in this way it will force Python to use `OpenSSL` implementation via `pyOpenSSL`.