# Why doesn't Requests skip the certificate?

Tags: python, python-requests

When executing a cUrl request :

```
curl  -k -u test:123 -i -X  POST -H "Content-Type: text/xml" "https://127.0.0.1:8085/q/status.xml"
```

I get an answer , everything works fine

But when executed via Requests:

```html
    import requests

headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'text/xml',
}

response = requests.post('https://127.0.0.1:8085/q/status.xml', headers=headers, verify=False, auth=('test', '123'))
```

I get an error `- requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='127.0.0.1', port=8085): Max retries exceeded with url: /q/status.xml (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: UNSUPPORTED_PROTOCOL] unsupported protocol (_ssl.c:997)')))`

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "skip the certificate"? If you're sending a request by HTTPS then the request must be encrypted, otherwise it's not HTTPS. And you need the server's certificate in order to encrypt the request in a way that the server can decrypt.

Comment: It may be that your requests library version is too new and does not allow using the ciphers that your local OpenSSL is using.

Comment: @RobertLee yes, I need TLS v1. How to set the version in requests

Comment: @kaya3 I wanted to say ignore the check

Comment: Another way is to just downgrade the use of the library https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62306296/how-to-use-tls-1-0-with-python-3-8

Answer (score 0):

the issue has been resolved by downgrading the python version to 3.6